# Issue with scroll arrows appearing when there are not enough tags to scroll in only windows

Tags: ios, windows, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXXd0.png)In my website, the scroll arrows are made to appear when there are more tags. But in windows, it is appearing though it is not necessary. But in macos it is working well. I have attached the screenshot. please help me

[image]

This is the site url:

https://www.sportingnews.com/jp/wwe/news/wwe-%E4%B8%AD%E9%82%91%E7%9C%9F%E8%BC%94shinsuke-nakamura-usa-days%E9%80%A3%E8%BC%89%E7%AC%AC1%E5%9B%9E%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%8C%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E3%81%A0%E3%83%91%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC/lvlwqx9qewyp1c2ne11ft4vdq

in windows os, in footer the scroll arrow is displaying even-though the tags are less. but in ios, it is loading fine as it should be. so any ideas to fix that?

Comment: Do you have some `overflow-x` parameters? Provide some code, please.

Comment: @Tarasovych i have provided.

Comment: I think that all code doesn't connected with arrows issue...

Comment: In script.js file the functionality for scroll arrows given. In the index file the html codes are provided. if u do inspect element, it will be easy to find

Comment: @Tarasovych i have attached the screenshot of the site above.